grant access to alter a table in postgres
Suppose in Postgres, there is a table ("tableA") that is owned by the role "tableA_owner".
"tableA" has a column called "types", which has an enum type ("myEnum"), and this enum is also owned by "tableA_owner".
Now, if "myEnum" needs to include new enums into it, or "myEnum" needs to be updated into a set of totally different values (but they are still unique), "tableA_owner" needs to update the "tableA" column types and update "myEnum" list, which is fine. But what if this happens frequently, and I want to leverage this enum updating situation to other users, instead of letting "tableA_owner" handle it every time?
How to design ownership and grant resources access to achieve goal above? I know that "tableA_owner" can grant INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE access to other users, etc, but altering a resources requires ownership access.
PS:
1, for the safety concern, I do not want to grant this "tableA_owner" role to others, since there are other tables owned by "tableA_owner", and I want to keep them safe.
2, I do want the column "types" to be enum.
